# appendTo/prependTo but instead of adding I want to replace the content. htmlTo?

Tags: jquery

Quick jquery question:
 I know about appendTo and prependTo but is there maybe something like htmlTo? Yeah, I know it sounds silly but instead of adding elements like appendto and prependTo do I want to replace the html.

```
$("<div>World</div>").htmlTo($("#Hello"));
```

So I want the div with World to replace all the content in the element with id Hello.

**Edit:**
Thanks everybody for the answers but I think I wasn't clear. I am chaining a lot of functions onto one element and at the end I clone that element and I want to add it to an other div.

```
$("#World").hide().clone().htmlTo($("#Hello"));
```

Yes, I could just write it the other way around but I would like to only have 1 chain.

Comment: I updated my question maybe I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the other way around:

```
$('#Hello').html($('#World').html());
```

Or create a plugin that reverses the chain:

```
$.fn.htmlTo = function(elem) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(elem).html($(this).html());
    });
}

$('#World').htmlTo('#Hello');
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work as well:

```
$("<div>World</div>").appendTo($("#Hello").empty());
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your edit, if you do not care about moving the actual DIV container and merely it's contents you could easily do:

```
$('#Hello').html($('#World').hide().html());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it the other way around. I currently have the $("<div>World</div>") selected and not the element with the id Hello.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$("<div>World</div>").appendTo($("#Hello").html(''));
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("<div>World</div>").html($("#Hello").html());`

Comment: Doesn't this replace the content of $("<div>World</div>") with the content of $("#Hello").html()? Cause that's not what I want at all.